# Default pagination widget in TYPo3 9.5.5 displayed only the first result

Tags: pagination, widget, fluid, typo3-9.x

Any of my pagination widget takes no link action and shows only the first result stack. The currentpage parameter is still existing in the url.

TYPO3 9.5.5

Comment: Can you post your fluid code and an example url like it is generated right now?

Answer (score 0):

Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh4V8.png

generated URL:

index.php?id=12&tx_topseries_listview%5B%40widget_0%5D%5BcurrentPage%5D=3